# How to bind data to only one of the children which was created using `ngFor`?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I want to make a click-to-show-next-picture gallery to show the next picture, feel like a gallery. I am trying the 'bind data' to child approach. but when I clicked one of the images, every images was binded to the data, and show the same picture. I am trying to change one image.

Here is the html look like. I create the images using `ngFor.`

```
<ion-slide *ngFor='let voucher of vouchers; let i=index'>
      <ion-card class='slide-card'>
        <ion-row class='image-box-row' align-items-end>
          <ion-col no-padding>
            <span class='image-box'>
              <img id='switchableImage' [src]='imageUrl' (click)='switchImage(i)'>
            </span>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row class='bottom-content-row'>
          <ion-col class='bottom-content' text-left>
            <span id='voucherName'>{{voucher.voucherName}}</span>
            <span id='quantitySold'>{{voucher.quantitySold}} Sold</span>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-card>
    </ion-slide>
```

and this is the ts file, assigning the 'imageUrl' the value from the array of objects.

```
switchImage(i) {
    console.log('slides ' + i + ' is tapped');
    this.counter += 1;
    console.log('counter is ' + this.counter);
    if (this.counter > this.vouchers[i].voucherImages.length -1) {
      this.counter = 0;
    }
    console.log(this.vouchers[i].voucherImages[this.counter]);
    this.imageUrl = this.vouchers[i].voucherImages[this.counter];
  }
```

My array of object look like this

```
public vouchers: any = [
    {
      voucherId: 1,
      restaurantId: 1,
      voucherImages: [
        '../../assets/imgs/set1.jpg',
        '../../assets/imgs/set1_2.jpg'
      ],
      voucherName: 'Valuable One Person Set Meal',
      suitablePax: 1,
      quantitySold: 119,
      newPrice: 20,
      basePrice: 25,
      currency: 'RM'
    },
    {
      voucherId: 2,
      restaurantId: 1,
      voucherImages: [
        '../../assets/imgs/set2.jpeg',
        '../../assets/imgs/set2_2.jpg',
        '../../assets/imgs/set2_3.jpg'
      ],
      voucherName: 'Romantic Two Person Steak Meal',
      suitablePax: 2,
      quantitySold: 119,
      newPrice: 89.9,
      basePrice: 120,
      currency: 'RM'
    }
]
```

Or do you guys have a better way to make a click to switch image gallery? I don't left much brain juice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add a new property to every voucher object, it will be the index of every voucher gallery :

```
 {
      voucherId: 1,
      restaurantId: 1,
      voucherImages: [
        '../../assets/imgs/set1.jpg',
        '../../assets/imgs/set1_2.jpg'
      ],
      voucherName: 'Valuable One Person Set Meal',
      suitablePax: 1,
      quantitySold: 119,
      newPrice: 20,
      basePrice: 25,
      currency: 'RM'
      index: 0
  }
```

Then, in your HTML, on the source of the image, set your voucherImages and the selected index.

```
<img id='switchableImage' [src]='voucher.voucherImages[voucher.index]' (click)='switchImage(i)'>
```

And just increase the voucher index at every click :

```
switchImage(i) {
    console.log('slides ' + i + ' is tapped');
    this.vouchers[i].index += 1;
    console.log('counter is ' + this.vouchers[i].index);
    if (this.vouchers[i].index > this.vouchers[i].voucherImages.length -1) {
      this.vouchers[i].index = 0;
    }
    console.log(this.vouchers[i].voucherImages[this.vouchers[i].index]);
  }
```

The index property replaces your counter

Comment: Omg, it works like charm!!! thank you very much for solving this problem saperlipopette! :)